# A calculate of curvature connecting intuitional images

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

When I read this [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor) (picture below is from it), it's so great that explain what  the Riemann curvature tensor is.But I get stuck in the calculate in the red box. How to calculate it ?

Because English is not my first language, if there are any mistake ,please tell me or edit it. Thanks.

> [image]

Comment: I am not sure what kind of answer you are looking for. Would it help to have a low-dimensional example, like a surface embedded in Euclidean 3-space?

Comment: @Justpassingby  I want to know why the left part equal to middle part in the red box. I mean that  how to compute it.